# Give input field a value with Jquery in Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to give a set of input fields a value. 
It's not clear in advance how many input fields have to be filled in, but they all have the same class

When I call the id of the first input field like this it works:

```
$('#order_order_articles_attributes_0_workload', row).val((price / 125).toFixed(2))
```

When I call the class like this it doesn't work:

```
$('td.input.workload', row).val((price / 125).toFixed(2))
```

The haml code looks like this:

```
%td.input.workload= order_article_f.input :workload, value: "0", label: false, input_html: { class: 'article_workload' }
```

How can I get this working for the class?

Comment: What's `row`? Impossible to help without knowing the context within which you're querying. (Although I always would use `$(row).find(...)`) Is `row` a jQuery select result?

Comment: row = $(this).parents("tr:first")

Comment: And it's in this method: $(input).on "change", ->

Comment: Isn't `val` for form fields? You're calling `val` on a table cell, no? What if you call it on the input element inside the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is not picking up the input field:

```
$('td.input.workload', row).val((price / 125).toFixed(2))
```

this rule is trying to set a value on td element that have class "input workload" like this.

```
<table><tr><td class="input workload">is trying to set value here</td></tr></table>
```

I create a fiddle with an example to set value for all input.

https://jsfiddle.net/tjecuh3m/

I hope I've helped.

Comment: I had to call it like this: 'td.workload input' instead of this: 'td.input.workload' thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to help